# Android edittext focus change keyboard hides view

Tags: android, android-edittext, keyboard, grid, focus

When I focus on another element in my app (landscape), the keyboard goes over my view that should be displayed, which I do not really want.

Code:

```
<activity
            android:name=".activity.ReportsEditActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_reports_edit"
            android:parentActivityName=".activity.MainActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateVisible">      
        </activity>
```

The edittext:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/report_template_grid_multi_line_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/grid_element_top_and_bottom_padding"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/grid_padding"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/grid_padding"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/grid_element_top_and_bottom_padding"
        android:gravity="top|start"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/grid_element_top_and_bottom_padding"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/grid_element_top_and_bottom_padding"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/grid_element_top_and_bottom_padding"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/grid_element_top_and_bottom_padding"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:textColor="@color/darkGray"
        android:textSize="@dimen/grid_text_size_small" />
```

This is fine:

[image]

But this is not fine, this occurs after clikcing on the edittext above the previous one when the keyboard is open

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

```
<activity
 android:name=".activity.ReportsEditActivity"
 android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
 android:label="@string/title_activity_reports_edit"
 android:parentActivityName=".activity.MainActivity"
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">      
</activity>
```